# Forced Oscillations and Complex Representation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, complex-numbers, linear-systems

> An oscillating force $F \cos \omega t = \Re\{Fe^{i\omega t}\}$, where $F$ is real, is applied to a mass $m$ on the end of a spring with spring constant $k$. The displacement, $x$, of the particle can be written as $\Re\{z\}$. Explain why $z$ obeys the equation $m\ddot{z} = −kz + Fe^{i\omega t}$ and show that $z = Ae^{i\omega t}$ is a solution to the equation.

So I know how to write a force equation in terms of $x$ from $F = ma$ (i.e., $m\ddot{x} = -kx + F\cos \omega t$) assuming no friction since it wasn't stated in the question, but then I don't know how to put $z$ in to that — why can I replace $x$ with $z$?

I also don't know how to show that $Ae^{i\omega t}$ is a solution, do I just put it in and then say it is a solution when $F - kA  = -m\omega^2$?

Comment: You never said what $z$ actually is. Also a solution to a differential equation is a function that makes the equation true. Just like how solutions to algebraic expressions are values of the variables that make the equations true.

Comment: I believe the prompt is in error. While it's true that $z$ obeying that equation *is* a solution to $x = \Re(z)$, it's not the only solution since **the imaginary part of $z$ is not constrained by either of the first two sentences.**

Comment: In other words, $z = Ae^{i \omega t}$ definitely makes the first two sentences work, but so does $z = A \cos(\omega t) + i * 5$

Comment: I'm thinking that a forced oscillation with no damping can only have a transient solution.

Answer (score 1):

> why can I replace x with z?

In this example, you are *designing* a complex number $z(t)$ so that its real part is equal to the $x$ variable which you care about. Therefore you wish to design $z$ so that, if $x=\Re(z)$,

$$m\ddot{x} = −kx + Fe^{i\omega t}$$

By design, then, you can replace $x$ with $\Re(z)$.

The reason to do this is that complex numbers are sometimes mathematically simpler to deal with than real numbers. In particular you will be dealing with exponentials rather than cosines.

> Explain why $z$ obeys the equation $m\ddot{z} = −kz + Fe^{i\omega t}$

Like Senor O said in the comments, there is a bit of an issue with this. Not any $z$ whose real part is $x$ must satisfy this equation: only the real part of $z$ should, and the imaginary part is free. However, a straightforward (and also useful) choice for $z$ is the one which satisfies the equation above. Then the real part of $z$ will also satisfy it, as we wanted.

> I also don't know how to show that $Ae^{i\omega t}$ is a solution, do I just put it in and then say it is a solution when $F - kA  = -m\omega^2$?

Exactly; that is the meaning of "is a solution".